# XSLT date format using month with words

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, date-format

Does anyone knows how to convert this date '2018-09-24T00:00:00' to this:

September 24th, 2018

using XSTL V1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

**XML**

```
<date>2018-09-24T00:00:00</date>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring(date, 6, 2)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$month=1">January</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=2">February</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=3">March</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=4">April</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=5">May</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=6">June</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=7">July</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=8">August</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=9">September</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=10">October</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=11">November</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=12">December</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="day" select="number(substring(date, 9, 2))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$day=1 or $day=21 or $day=31">st</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$day=2 or $day=22">nd</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>th</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(date, 1, 4)"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>September 24th, 2018</output>
```

Comment: It's a very complete template and it works like a charm, thank you!