# Transforming xml using xslt with additional information

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datetime, xslt

I'm currently working with a xsl style sheet that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54893329/3016153) and I am trying to add a certain improvement in order to render the time with the date .

When passed a particular date currently the output renders as `<output>September 24th, 2020</output>` but I would also like to include time something similar to below

September 24th, 2020 09:30

Any idea how I can make that improvement

The input is as :- `2020-09-24T09:30:00+00:00`

My code is as follows

```
string xsltPath = @ "D:\xslt\xslt.xml";

string xslt = File.ReadAllText(xsltPath);

var oldDocument = new XDocument(
 new XElement("date", "2020-09-24T09:30:00+00:00")

);

var newDocument = new XDocument();

using(var stringReader = new StringReader(xslt)) {
 using(XmlReader xsltReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader)) {
  var transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
  transformer.Load(xsltReader);
  using(XmlReader oldDocumentReader = oldDocument.CreateReader()) {
   using(XmlWriter newDocumentWriter = newDocument.CreateWriter()) {
    transformer.Transform(oldDocumentReader, newDocumentWriter);
   }
  }
 }
}

string result = newDocument.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The XSL style sheet is defined as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring(date, 6, 2)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$month=1">January</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=2">February</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=3">March</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=4">April</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=5">May</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=6">June</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=7">July</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=8">August</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=9">September</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=10">October</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=11">November</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=12">December</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="day" select="number(substring(date, 9, 2))"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$day=1 or $day=21 or $day=31">st</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$day=2 or $day=22">nd</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>th</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(date, 1, 4)"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that with .NET/C# you could opt for XSLT 2 or 3 with Saxon 9 .NET and then use `format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(date), '[MNn] [D1o], [Y] [H01]:[m01]')`. If you want to use XslCompiledTransform I would consider using an extension to the .NET framework's date formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the time from you date using a substring :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring(date, 6, 2)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$month=1">January</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=2">February</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=3">March</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=4">April</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=5">May</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=6">June</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=7">July</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=8">August</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=9">September</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=10">October</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=11">November</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$month=12">December</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="day" select="number(substring(date, 9, 2))"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$day=1 or $day=21 or $day=31">st</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$day=2 or $day=22">nd</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>th</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(date, 1, 4)"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(date, 12, 5)"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknt7